# INSERT INTO using multiple WITH clauses

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert record with a trigger. And the insert multiple values from different tables, so I am using multiple CTEs to hold values for them.

Basic structure of the trigger function is like this:

```
WITH prop1 AS (
 ...
), prop2 AS (
 ...
), prop3 As (
 ...
)
INSERT INTO table (..)
VALUES (prop1.attribute,prop2.attribute,prop3.attribute);
```

But this does not work.

The 'prop1.attribute' attribute fetching causing the fail.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Well, you need to join the CTEs somehow. Do you have ID or something else?

Comment: props have the entires rows for now. couple of properties are required from each of them.

Comment: How are the CTEs related to each other? I'm afraid you need to join them somehow

Comment: Some CTEs are related and some are unrelated.

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: Add some sample data and the exact expected result. Preferably reproduce your example in a fiddle ;)

Comment: Do a SELECT instead of INSERT. Do you get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to SELECT from your CTEs, and also join between them in some logic. I'll put CROSS JOIN in below example which will multiply every row from each CTE with every row from each of other other two

```
WITH prop1 AS (
 ...
), prop2 AS (
 ...
), prop3 As (
 ...
)
INSERT INTO table (..)
SELECT prop1.attribute,prop2.attribute,prop3.attribute
FROM prop1 
CROSS JOIN prop2
CROSS JOIN prop3
```

Preferably replace CROSS JOINs with INNER:

```
FROM prop1 
INNER JOIN prop2 ON prop2.someId = prop1.someId
INNER JOIN prop3 ON prop3.someId = prop1.someId
```